# ZIP file permissions from PHP script

Tags: php, linux, unix, jenkins, file-permissions

I am trying to update or overwrite a archive via php but its not working even the user has all the access rights to folder in Linux. I can create or overwrite `csv` file but not `zip`.If i run `php` via command line then it works but not via Jenkins.Does user needs different permissions for `csv` and `zip` because for `csv` i have no problems.Here is what i tried

```
$cmd = "zip -FSr test test.csv";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: i am calling script from jenkins